# GIMP crashes on launch

Tags: gtk, gimp, crash

When launching GIMP, I receive the following message:

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"
Bus error (core dumped)
```

Before it was also included:

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
```

But it seems to have been resolved after installing the `libcanberra-gtk-module:i386` package.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated as I use GIMP regularly.

Comment: Are you using a 64bit OS with a 32bit version of GIMP?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm using the 64bit version.

I managed to resolve the issue by removing the GIMP configuration folder in my home directory. Launched as normal after that.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it resolved! Thanks for posting your solution as this may be helpful for other users facing this problem.

Answer (score 7):

Resolved problem by removing `.gimp-2.8` folder in home

Comment: Would you accept you own answer as that what works for you. Please, review https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer